# How to sign transaction from tz2 address?

Tags: transactions, security, cryptography, tezos-signer, crypto

Can i sign my transaction if i use secp256k1? And how it do?
If i'm using sign function from eztz lib, i takes

```
TypeError: invalid privateKey length
```

Private key coded using secp256k1 curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must sign transactions from tz2 addresses with secp256k1. Eztz's sign function uses Ed25519, so that wont work. Easiest would probably be to just replace libsodium in eztz with something like bitcoinjs-lib.

Comment: Thanks, already found in sotez.